# CSRF check failed when calling Nextcloud API from an Android app

Tags: java, android, csrf, nextcloud

I created an Android app (by Java) to connect to Nextcloud server. Both of them are virtual machines and in the same physical machine. For the connection, I used https://github.com/nextcloud/android-library.
For my APIs, I added annotation `@NoCSRFRequired` and called them from the server successfully.

[image]

When I call them from terminal in Android Studio, I got the error:

> Current user is not logged in

even I enter the same username and password. In some case, I have error:

> CSRF check failed

I tried to set the header `OCS-APIRequest: true` in my Android app but nothing changes.

[image]

[image]